# vis.js axis value labels in string format

Tags: javascript, vis.js

I am using vis.js for creating 3D surface graph, and it is working fine but I want to show string on X, and Y axis at the place of numbers. I read the docs but there is no property in vis.js for showing string on X, and Y axis.

From the following link I found this answer:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/chap-links-library/8yMnVmkvipc

So, can anyone help me to customize vis.js file for showing axis values in string format.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

See the options `xValueLabel`, `yValueLabel`, and `zValueLabel` in the docs http://visjs.org/docs/graph3d/#Configuration_Options

Comment: Strange, that is only for 3d vis graphs. Don't see a similar option for 2d vis graphs.